# Linux client: mount.cifs works but net time doesn't

Tags: samba, smbclient

I'm running a Linux VM that needs to access files on Windows machines. For that I have a bunch of CIFS mounts in /etc/fstab that work fine. Idiotically the Windows machines have free-running system clocks not synced to anything, so I also want to know their respective local times. I'm using "net -I xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx time" for that. Every now and then I'll get "Protocol negotiation failed: ERRDOS:ERRnomem", but that usually goes away on its own after a while (the Windows machines are polled round robin every few minutes). Now for the past few days one Windows box is permamently stuck with this error, and I don't know why. "net" version is 4.10.16.

Background: The Windows hosts are dedicated controllers for industrial production tools in a factory that run 24/7. Windows versions range from 7 to 10. Therefore I am extremely reluctant to change any system settings or the registry. I'm just trying to understand the technical background of this error. I saw answers on related issues suggesting to change the memory mgmt on the Win machines which doesn't make sense to me because just sending back the system time can't be such a memory intensive operation.

That said ... is there an alternative way to inquire the Windows computer's system time?

(Don't make me get into the reasons why the tool manufacturer can't just make their controller's clock run in sync with the network time. It's an abyss of idiocy IMO).